# using ant design switch inside Forms

Tags: reactjs, antd

What's the correct way to use ant design switch inside, I could not get much from the official documentation.
[Switch-Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/switch/)

Here's how I am using it.

```
<Form form={form} layout="vertical">
  <Form.Item
    label="Description"
    name="description"
    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Enter a description' }]}
  >
    <Input placeholder="Enter Description" />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item name="switch" noStyle valuePropName="checked">
    <Switch checkedChildren="Yes" unCheckedChildren="No" />
    <span>Chargable</span>
  </Form.Item>

  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      form
        .validateFields()
        .then((values) => {
          form.resetFields()
          onCreate(values)
        })
        .catch((info) => {
          console.log('Validate Failed:', info)
        })
    }}
  >
    Save
  </Button>
</Form>
```

onCreate does no take the value from the switch, It does take it from the description

```
const onCreate = (values) => {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix it but doing the following.

```
<td>
  <Form.Item valuePropName="checked" name="status" noStyle>
    <Switch checkedChildren="Yes" unCheckedChildren="No" />
  </Form.Item>
  <span className="ml-2">Status Enabled</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can nest Form.Item like the [code](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-other), like the InputNumber.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your values are `{description: "foo", switch: undefined}`?

In my demo, [switch demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xiao-yan-qi-ta-zu-jian-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-nhxt7?file=/index.js), I add initialValue to Switch, so when I get values from the form, I get `{description: "111", switch: true}`.

I don't know whether this is what your mean.

---

or you can use like this

```
<Form.Item label="foo">         
  <Form.Item name="bar">           
    <Switch />         
  </Form.Item>         
  <span className="ant-form-text">Some text you want</span>       

</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have forked your sandbox and recreated the error. It is because I am not using a label, Instead I have a span element, I have done it because I put custom styles in my span and a label cannot do that for me.

Comment: the forked version can not recreate the error, if you have left some code or you have not saved your version.

Comment: Oh no I just checked, But I was able to fix it, thank you for your help . The way you have done it is correct as well but I had that error because I also had a span element inside Form.Item, which is not allowed in antd and caused the error. I have put the solution below. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. You had that error because you also had a span element inside Form.Item, which is not allowed in antd. Further more, according to the [antd api doc](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-other), the more appropriate solution like this ```<Form.Item label="foo">
        <Form.Item name="bar">
          <Switch />
        </Form.Item>
        <span className="ant-form-text">Some text you want</span>
      </Form.Item>```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you must only have one child inside a `Form.Item` component. Remove the `span` besides your Switch component and it will work.